# SSRS 2008 R2 Intelligent Mail Barcode Generation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, barcode, barcode-printing

I have a SSRS report that is used to generate invoices. I am trying to dynamically generate Intelligent Mail Barcode (IMB) at the bottom of the invoice, based on the dataset that is being used for the report. I have found documentation for using [IMB](https://ribbs.usps.gov/index.cfm?page=intellmailmailpieces) and have installed their font. I have been able to use the font inside my report.

[image]

I had placed a random Encoded 65-character String that I pulled off of one of their PDF documents.

I am a little stuck with how to use the font. Would it be possible to implement some parameters that change the text encode the text I need? Or would the only solution be to use an outside code base in a dll. to be able to encode the information into the right combinations of "D's, A's, F's, and T's."

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with using the IMB inside reports and could point me in the right direction. I would prefer not to have to use an outside solution (paid apps, etc.).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, but where are you running into problems? Your question makes it sounds like everything is working for you.

Comment: My problem is that I am stuck on how to implement using the font. I have installed the font and placed a random string of : "DDAFFFDAFTFDFFAAATTTDDFFTFADDFAFTTDAAAAAADFTTFDTAFDDTDDADATDAFAFF" into it to show it works. Now I need to be able to produce the encoded results- through parameters, or code. I was just looking for some possible guidance on where to start. (I know SSRS can be a little quirky and may need it done a particular way).